# flashplayer.dmg is in use and can't empty Trash

Tags: macos, malware

I accidentally downloaded malware: something posing as Flash Player in flashplayer.dmg. I did *not* install it, but deleted the dmg file. Now I want to delete my trash bin, but I can't. It says: 'trash can't be emptied, flash player.dmg is in use.'
How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you reboot yet?

Comment: It's likely the dmg was mounted when you trashed it. Trashing the file will not unmount it automatically, and being mounted counts as in use.

Answer (score 7):

- open `Terminal.app`
- type `rm .Trash/flash_player.dmg` and press Enter. This removes the file.
- reboot
- check whether the file is gone from the Trashcan

It might be helpful to run a malware cleaner afterwards as well to make sure nothing else got infected.

Comment: It's gone now, but Malwarebytes didn't identify/find it before I removed it. Should have found it I'd say? :/

Comment: @KirstenVerdel Hard to say, now that the malware seems to be gone.

Answer (score 3):

First, reboot. Second hold down the <kbd>Option</kbd> while selecting Empty Trash from the Finder menu.

Failing that boot in Safe Mode (hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key while booting your Mac). And try emptying the trash again.

Failing **that** you may want to try a free malware cleaner.

Comment: I tried the option/secure trash emptying thing. That works. Don't know if the problem is gone now. I already tried Malwarebytes before I did that, but it didn't find anything strange on my Mac related to flash player.dmg. Hope it's solved... thanks!!